# How to show Twenty-sixteen them menu under logo?

Tags: theme-twenty-sixteen

I try to change WordPress Twenty-sixteen them.

I check the CSS carefully, can't finger out how could be the main menu display on the right of logo(and name of website).

No float, no inline-block.

I try to add float or display as block to menu and logo, doesn't work at all.How they do it?

Answer (score 0):

The header of Twenty-Sixteen uses flexbox for alignment.  You can set the flex direction of the site-header-main class to column to display the menu under the title/tagline/logo area:

```
    .site-header-main {
        flex-direction: column;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

In my suggestion, start a child theme of Twenty-sixteen theme,preferred way to Override parent theme functionalities and design.

Comment: while this might be the correct way to implement a solution, it does not actually provide a solution.